# optional regex lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get an optional lookahead but am having problems where as soon as I make it optional (add a `?` after it), it no longer matches even when the data is there.

As a brief summary, I'm trying to pull specific querystring params out of a URI.  Example:

```
/.*foo.html\??(?=.*foo=([^\&]+))(?=.*bar=([^\&]+))/
    .exec( 'foo.html?foo=true&bar=baz' )
```

I'll break that out a bit:

```
.*foo.html\??      // filename == `foo.html` + '?'
(?=.*foo=([^\&]+)) // find "foo=...." parameter, store the value
(?=.*bar=([^\&]+)) // find "bar=...." parameter, store the value
```

The above example works perfectly under the condition that both `foo` and `bar` exist as parameters in the querystring.  The issue is that I'm trying to make these optional, so I changed it to:

```
/.*foo.html\??(?=.*foo=([^\&]+))?(?=.*bar=([^\&]+))?/
                                ↑                  ↑
    Added these question marks ─┴──────────────────┘
```

and it no longer matches any parameters, though it still matches `foo.html`.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using regular expressions for this? Simply split the string and store the key/values pairs in an object.

Comment: @ThiefMaster -- Because I want to :)  And I want to even more now that it won't work.  In reality, it's simply because the code is much shorter when I just need to get 2 params.

Comment: Why do you need lookahead? To match foo.html?bar=baz&foo=true as well?

Comment: @Bergi - exactly.  At this point I'm more curious as to why the above won't work :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to put the question marks into the look-ahead:

```
...((?=(?:.*foo=([^\&]+))?)...
```

Looks odd, but I think a good-looking regex wasn't the aim :-)

Also, have you thought about this one?

```
/.*foo.html\??.*(?:foo|bar)=([^\&]+).*(?:bar|foo)=([^\&]+)/
```

Comment: Thanks, first one works.  I think this is required because the engine might be optimizing `(?=)?` out entirely (i.e. just ignoring it) since an optional non-matching regex is, well, pointless.  I just happen to be using it to catch something else.  Your 2nd one would work too, except it would need a few tweaks to make each param optional, and there's a little more logic after the fact since you need to figure out which param is where (you'd need to remove the two `?:`'s then check against those)

Comment: Anyway, making the lookahead optional would lead to matching an empty string.